# Show/hide datatable when display is set to none

Tags: javascript, html

I have a datatable , want to show/hide based on the flag,

```
<div class="enginestat" style="display: none;">

if (resp == 'Y') {
    $(".enginestat").show();
} else {
    $(".enginestat").hide();
}
```

The datatable doesnt show up properly, how to show/hide when I put display:none?

Comment: Did you test if that flag is being set?

Comment: yes, I could alert the flag. Also, I can see the blue table i think the container at the background but other than that nothing else coming up

Comment: What datatable? What is `resp`? When is this code executed? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] and more context to your code.

Comment: Your script is in $( document ).ready() ?

Comment: Yes, it is in doc.ready()

Comment: What do you mean with "datatable"? Is there some external data table component within the div?

Comment: What does this code do? Can you use Jsfiddle or the snippet tool to demonstrate the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2):

Use document.getElementByClassName("enginestat").style.display = "block"
and document.getElementByClassName("enginestat").style.display = "none"

Comment: You mean `document.getElementByClassName`. Either way, this is (roughly) equivalent to using jQuery's `show` and `hide` anyway.

Comment: Its `getElementsByClassName` by the way